# How to introduce typo in a string?

Tags: python, string

I would like to introduce typos in a string. I have a parameter typo_prob which would flip a character in a string with a probability of typo_prob.

For example, if typo_prob is 0.1, every tenth character will be replaced by a random character.

So far I am doing this:

```
message = "Where do you live?"
message = list(message)
n_chars_to_flip = round(len(message) * typo_prob)
pos_to_flip = []
for i in range(n_chars_to_flip):
    pos_to_flip.append(random.randint(0, len(message) - 1))
for pos in pos_to_flip:
    message[pos] = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
message = ''.join(message)
```

Please let me know if there is a more elegant or efficient way to do this.

Comment: Why not do it the obvious way?

Comment: What do you mean by the obvious way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd to this as following:

```
[x if random.random() >= 0.5 else random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for x in list(message)]
```

0.5 is the probabilty the character is replaced.

Comment: Since a `str` is expected, maybe `''.join(x if ...)`

Comment: random() return values [0,1) so better is to use `random() >= prob` to catch corner case when prob is 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
import string

message = "Where do you live?"
message = list(message)

for pos, char in enumerate(message):
    message[pos] = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) if random.random() < 0.1 else char

message = "".join(message)
```